# create setup with pre-install vc++2015 runtime like requirement

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2019, setup-project, setup-deployment

I am creating a setup and check the pre-requirement option of Visual Studio 2019 - Setup Project. However, I could not find a VC++2015 pre-requirement.

[image]

But I am using `CEFSHARP` and it is a requirement; I don't want to put people to install this manually, is there a way to add this as a requirement and automate the installation.

I don't know much about it; I don't even know how to actually say this: pre-requisites?

Also, the Visual Studio user interface is in Spanish; how do I change it to English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *actual* version number for Visual Studio 2015 is 14. See the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio/info) for more information about VS version numbers.

So, to have your "setup.exe" pre-install the redistributables required by CefSharp, select the **Visual C++ "14" Runtime Libraries (xxx)** appropriate for your target platform(s).

Furthermore, since VS-2015, the C++ Redistributable Pack has been 'unified' to work with software compiled with multiple versions of the toolset: Thus, the Visual C++ "14" Runtime Libraries are suitable also for software built with VS-2017 (v. 15) and VS-2019 (v. 16). [More info here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231080/discussion-between-gestion-soporte-and-adrian-mole).